Rebuilding Debian 12.01 kernel from sources, ends up with broken kernel
I have been trying to rebuild Debian bookworm distro from scratch.
Could you point me out where i am mistaken or use a wrong approach, please?
Let me first describe  my actions:

Rebuild a certain kernel from linux-6.1.37-1 sources, by running consequently cd linux-6.1.37/; fakeroot debian/rules source;  fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch. As a result i get a bunch of .deb packages, 3 of which are unsigned versions of amd64, cloud and RT kernels (btw. i have them installed and they work correctly)
I use those 3 unsigned kernels and linux-signed-amd64.dsc package with its dependencies, to generate signed kernels and buy running debuild -us -uc. As a result i get signed kernels(which installed on system brakes it, cannot be found any block devices anymore and rootfs) and dozens of .udeb files
I use debian installer sources and those the .udebs from step 2 to get vmlinuz and initrd.gz files for the installation. The ISO with these files is also not bootable

